# ¿Cómo puedo generar ejecutables de Perl?

Tags: perl

Estoy aprendiendo Perl y quisiera convertir mis scripts de Perl a ejecutables. He indagado por la web y me he conseguido el compilador de Perl pp, y quisiera saber cómo instalarlo, estoy utilizando Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Comentar que `pp` no es un "compilador" de perl como tal. Realmente lo que hace es montar un ejecutable que contiene dentro tu script, las dependencias y **el intérprete (es decir: perl.exe, dlls, etc)**

Answer (score 0):

En Ubuntu, debes usar el gestor de software e instalar el paquete libpar-packer-perl

Después, puedes consultar su página de manual (con el comando man), o leerlo en línea: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man3/pp.3pm.html

O leer la documentación y ver ejemplos en el sitio de MetaCPAN, donde está todo el software de Perl: https://metacpan.org/pod/pp

De todos modos, son muy pocas las ocasiones en las que necesitas convertir tus scripts a ejecutables. En la inmensa mayoría de las ocasiones te vale con dejarlos en forma de script, y llamarlos directamente desde el shell, el cron o cualquier otro método de ejecución del sistema operativo que uses.

Por ejemplo, si colocas tu script en /usr/local/bin, y le das permiso de ejecución (chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/tu-script.pl) a partir de ese momento lo podrás ejecutar desde cualquier sitio, invocando su nombre.

Comment: Me podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo de como instalarlo ( los comandos a ejecutar en consola)

Comment: Si apt está instalado, será algo así: apt install libpar-packer-perl

Comment: Puesto que cualquier distribución linux tiene Perl instalado, quizás el formato de salida más interesante sea 'par', en lugar de sacar un ejecutable. Así te evitas añadir el intérprete dentro del ejecutable.